# How to report abuse spam with X-AntiAbuse header which was added to track abuse?

Tags: email, spam

I've received the following spam e-mail (with the link to viagra site):

```
Return-Path: <silviani@server04.funet.co.il>
Received: from server04.funet.co.il (server04.funet.co.il. [212.29.215.70])
Received: from silviani by server04.funet.co.il with local (Exim 4.82) (envelope-from <silviani@server04.funet.co.il>)
From: silviani@server04.funet.co.il
Date: Tue, 09 Sep 2014 12:43:55 +0300
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - server04.funet.co.il
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [816 32007] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - server04.funet.co.il
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: server04.funet.co.il: authenticated_id: silviani/primary_hostname/system user
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: /usr/sbin/proxyexec -q -d -s /var/run/proxyexec/cagefs.sock/socket /bin/cagefs.server 
X-Source-Dir: silvianimberg.com:/public_html/wp-content/themes/ultimatum
"And that's it, then," Kira said. "He'll lose face, coming home like that. That's all the dangerous ones, if Gul Kaidan was right."
"Wesley, we all-"
"The circumstances are somewhat incongruous," Picard agreed. "It usually takes some compelling motivations to prompt such a rapprochement. Investigating those motivations will be part of our assignment. Mr. Data, the pertinent background, if you please."
"Now you are practicing telepathy," he observed. "But," he added, "you are not strange, Tasha."
Amazingly, other people were just walking past as if nothing was happening. What the blazes was wrong with these people?
```

which says that this message is tracked so I can send the abuse report. How I can do that? What's the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read the headers, you see that the system you received that message from is `server04.funet.co.il. [212.29.215.70]` so that's where the spam should be reported.

Now that domain does not appear to be available in English so your first option is to follow [RFC 2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt) recommendation and send the complain in English (with all the details about this spam) to abuse@funet.co.il.

The second option is to find someone who can read Hebrew or use an [automated translation tool](https://translate.google.com/) to check the target domain (`funet.co.il`). if you do that, you'll notice that it's actually an alias for http.co.il and that the abuse report address they suggest you use is actually `abuse@http.co.il`

Another possibility is to use an automated spam reporting service to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Where can you confirm server04.funet.co.il as IP 212.29.215.70 ?

Do a whois on the first IP, check the admin email adresse, or send a mail to abuse@.... domain name of this IP.

Here:

```
$ whois 212.29.215.70
[Requête en cours whois.ripe.net]
[whois.ripe.net]
... /CUT PART / ...

% Information related to '212.29.215.64 - 212.29.215.95'

% Abuse contact for '212.29.215.64 - 212.29.215.95' is 'abuse@013netvision.co.il'

inetnum:        212.29.215.64 - 212.29.215.95
netname:        PIGLILOTH-1
descr:          Pi Gliloth Ltd.
... /CUT PART / ...
address:        Send Spam and Abuse complaints to barakabuse@netvision013.co.il
abuse-mailbox:  barakabuse@netvision013.co.il
... /CUT PART / ...
source:         RIPE # Filtered

person:         Dudi Maya
... /CUT PART / ...
```

Just transfert the mail with all the header to : barakabuse@netvision013.co.il and abuse@013netvision.co.il